# VBA - Loop until answer = VbNo

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am building a little code to track some stocks, and I was wondering if there is a way to turn the code below into a "do until answer = vbNo" loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A Tricky Do...Loop

```vb
Sub CollectTickers()
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Collect Tickers" ' adjust!
    Const AAPL As String = "Default" ' adjust!

    Dim Tickers As Object: Set Tickers = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Tickers.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim Answer As Long
    Dim Ticker As Variant ' so it can be used in a 'For Each...Next' loop
    Dim FirstAdded As Boolean
    
    Do Until Answer = vbNo
        
        If Not FirstAdded Then ' first
            Ticker = InputBox("Please input your first stock ticker!", _
                PROC_TITLE, AAPL)
            If Len(Ticker) > 0 Then ' the 1st ticker is not an empty string
                FirstAdded = True
            Else ' the 1st ticker is an empty string
                MsgBox "Sorry, you need to input at least one ticker symbol! " _
                    & "Goodbye!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Else ' not the first
            Ticker = InputBox("Please input another stock ticker!", _
                PROC_TITLE, AAPL)
        End If
        
        If Len(Ticker) > 0 Then ' ticker is not an empty string
            If Not Tickers.Exists(Ticker) Then
                Tickers(Ticker) = Empty
            Else
                MsgBox "You already added the '" & Ticker & "' ticker.", _
                    vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
            End If
        Else ' ticker is an empty string but it's not the first
            ' do nothing!?
        End If
        
        Answer = MsgBox("Do you want to input another ticker?", _
            vbQuestion + vbYesNo, PROC_TITLE)
        
    Loop

    MsgBox "You added the following " _
        & IIf(Tickers.Count = 1, "", Tickers.Count & " ") & "stock ticker" _
        & IIf(Tickers.Count = 1, "", "s") & ":" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Join(Tickers.Keys, vbLf), vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
   
    For Each Ticker In Tickers
        ' Do your thing with the tickers, e.g.
        Debug.Print Ticker
    Next Ticker

End Sub
```

Comment: Oh my god, this is absolutely beautiful! thank you so much!